# Netbeans Browser Select Not Working

Tags: debugging, browser, netbeans

I am running NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 on Windows 7 and am trying to debug my web app in browsers other than my system default one (Chrome). When I go to the "Tools - Options - General" menu in NetBeans there is a dropdown box for selecting the Web Browser. When I select a browser other than Chrome (I have them all installed) NetBeans still insists on using Chrome whenever I click on the "Run" or "Debug" project buttons. From everything I've read online this should work and am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. "Tools - Options - General" and selecting a Web Browser was not the right place. I had to right-click on my project, go to properties, click on the "Run" option in the Categories pane and select the browser to be used from there.